# Wordpress Categories - Make Non-clickable

Tags: wordpress

I'm working on my main menu in wordpress.  I have three options for the menu.  First, if a category has one post attached, redirect to display that post.  Second, if there is more than one post attached to a category, display the category page with a list of those posts.  Third, if there is NOT a post associated directly with that category, do nothing.  Essentially, I want the third option to be an unclickable link.  Below is my code (which doesn't seem to work.)  I have tried various combinations and yet am still stuck.  Any thoughts?

```
<?php 
    if(have_posts()) :
        $category = get_the_category();
        if ($category[0]->category_count == 1) :
            while (have_posts()) : the_post();
                wp_redirect(get_permalink($post->ID));
            endwhile;
        elseif ($category[0]->category_count !='') :
            wp_redirect(get_permalink($post->ID));

        else: 

        endif;      
    endif;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
elseif (!empty($category[0]->category_count))
```

Instead of

```
elseif ($category[0]->category_count !='') :
```

Comment: Now I'm thinking the problem is that if the subcategories have posts, the blank category is reading that as if it has a post.  How do I distinguish that.  (Sorry if I sound extremely green here.  I guess I am...)